# Why the backtrace may be not correct when enable tail optimization

Tags: gcc, gdb, clang, compiler-optimization

Per https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html:

> Note that certain compiler optimizations may interfere with obtaining a valid backtrace. Function inlining causes the inlined function to not have a stack frame; tail call optimization replaces one stack frame with another; frame pointer elimination will stop backtrace from interpreting the stack contents correctly.

I want to know why it should happen when enabling tail optimization and how to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know why it should happen when enabling tail optimization

It will happen with tail call optimization because your recursive function will not be recursive after the compiler is done with it, or a tail recursive function will be entirely missing from the call stack.

Example:

```
// t.c
int foo() { return 42; }
int bar() { return foo(); }
int main() { return bar(); }

gcc -O2 -fno-inline t.c && gdb -q ./a.out

(gdb) b foo
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1140
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/a.out

Breakpoint 1, 0x0000555555555140 in foo ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000555555555140 in foo ()
#1  0x00007ffff7dfad0a in __libc_start_main (main=0x555555555040 <main>, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdc08, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffdbf8) at ../csu/libc-start.c:308
#2  0x000055555555507a in _start ()
```

Where did `main()` and `bar()` go? We know that `main()` must still be on the stack.

They were tail call optimized:

```
(gdb) disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000555555555040 <+0>:     xor    %eax,%eax
   0x0000555555555042 <+2>:     jmpq   0x555555555150 <bar>
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) disas bar
Dump of assembler code for function bar:
   0x0000555555555150 <+0>:     xor    %eax,%eax
   0x0000555555555152 <+2>:     jmp    0x555555555140 <foo>
End of assembler dump.
```

> how to avoid it.

The only way to avoid it is to disable tail call optimization (with `-fno-optimize-sibling-calls`):

```
gcc -O2 -fno-inline t.c -fno-optimize-sibling-calls && gdb -q ./a.out

(gdb) b foo
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1140
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/a.out

Breakpoint 1, 0x0000555555555140 in foo ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000555555555140 in foo ()
#1  0x0000555555555157 in bar ()
#2  0x0000555555555047 in main ()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if there is a crash inside bar(), the backtrace still show the frame of bar(), that means the backtrace is still point to the instruction which caused the crash, I didn't see the case "tail call optimization replaces one stack frame with another"
`
`int foo() { return 42; }`
`int bar() { int a[10]; a[2000]=1; return foo(); }`
`int main() { return bar(); }`
`

Comment: @BiaoCao "the backtrace will show `bar()`" -- yes, but not `main()`. In other words, the backtrace is invalid in the sense that info is missing from it.